# Efficient way to find any key of array as a substring in a text

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, search

I have an input text

```
$text ="this is just a normal text with max length of 150 characters"
```

I have an array of size 400

```
$keywordArray = array("this","that","who","where","abuse","spam","..");
```

Now I want to find if this any substring of $text belongs to $keywordArray

One way is

```
1) break the $text in words 
2) take each word and check in the array 
          if it contains that word
                  return true;
3) exit
```

Please suggest any better solutions in php for this. 
Can I use a regex for this?
Or any other approach.
I need this for a webapp with huge number of web pages to filter out spam pages based on url's text.

And also can we handle this using .htaccess file (putting a rewrite rule).

```
Rewriterule (regex forspammedurls) spammedpage.php [L] 
Rewriterule (.*) normalpage.php [L]
```

Just want to understand, at php level or at Apache level I should handle this.
Please give your suggestions.
Thanks,

Comment: You want to find the words that are in your array? Or just find out if any of the words are in the array?

Comment: Simply compile the regex "\b(this|that|who|where|abuse|...)\b" and match the tested string against it

Comment: only want verify if any key exist in my text. need Boolean result

Comment: @onon15 ya that is a way. but is there any better approch. because that regex size will be pattern with 400 pipes.

Comment: 400 pipes will be reasonable, since the resulting regex will be compiled only the 1st time and brought up from the cache on subsequent calls. I expect that evaluation of this regex will be faster than searching for each word in the keyword array in the given string.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a short way

```
$words = str_word_count( $text, 1 );
$foundWords = array_intersect( $words, $keywordArray);
if ( count($foundWords) ) {
    // some words found
} else {
    // no words found
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use array_intersect to find matched words without looping:

```
$text ="this is just a normal text with max length of 150 characters";
$keywordArray = array("this","that","who","where","abuse","of");

$result = array_intersect($keywordArray,str_word_count($text,2));
if (count($result) > 0) {
    echo 'Matches found: ';
    var_dump($result);
}
```

Comment: is this is the most efficient way? and also can i handle this with .htaccess also?

Comment: Is it the most efficient way? - run some tests to see. What do you mean: "handle this with .htaccess"?

Comment: in Apache server there is a file .htaccess where you can put url rewrite rules. If I put regex in .htaccess  like --- regexforspam pages - showspampage.php [L]   --- others normalpage.php [L]

Comment: I know what an .htaccess file is. This is a PHP solution (as you'd tagged your question PHP)... it does not use regular expressions, and you can't ue it in an .htaccess file because it's PHP code... if you want something you can put in .htaccess, tag your question as htaccess and not as PHP

Comment: @MarkBaker - yes Mark, I am tagging it now. Actually I was trying to understand, If I handle this using .htaccess Or using php code. which one will be more efficient. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

While you could construct a regular expression it will be *long* and arguably *complex*.

Remember that PHP has a large amount of [String](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) and [Array](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) functions.

If you are only interested if an array key exists in certain string, using native functions like [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) and [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) is an strong alternative.

**Note:** I realize this is not an explicit *answer*. However, it is aimed helping readers [be a better PHP developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).